# Subsctract one array from another array in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 arrays like this :

```
VM.dataTotalList = result.map(item => {
                    return {
                      idEquipment : item['0'],
                      timestamp   : item['1'],
                      value       : item['2']
                    };
                });
```

```
VM.dataFreeList = result.map(item => {
                    return {
                      idEquipment : item['0'],
                      timestamp   : item['1'],
                      value       : item['2']
                    };
                });
```

I want to subtract only the property 'value' from the 2 arrays, and I want to have the same type of array as a result, can anyone show me the proper way to do it please?

Thanks!

**UPDATE1**

```
        VM.dataFreeList = [];
        VM.dataTotalList = [];
        /**
         * Getting the swap total value of an idequipment
         * */
        SwapDataService.getSwapTotalDataList().then((result) => {
            // change properties name of data array
            VM.dataTotalList = result.map(item => {
                return {
                  idEquipment : item['0'],
                  timestamp   : item['1'],
                  value       : parseInt(item['2'])
                };
            });
        }).then(() => {

        });

        /**
         * Getting the swap free value of an idequipment
         * */
        SwapDataService.getSwapFreeDataList().then((result) => {
            // change properties name of data array
            VM.dataFreeList = result.map(item => {
                return {
                  idEquipment : item['0'],
                  timestamp   : item['1'],
                  value       : parseInt(item['2'])
                };
            });
            $log.info('total', VM.dataTotalList);
            $log.info('free', VM.dataFreeList);
            VM.newdataList = VM.dataTotalList.map((item, index) => {
                item['value'] -= VM.dataFreeList[index]['value'];
                return item;
            });


            $log.info('new array', VM.newdataList);
        });
```

Here's how the data looks:

```
total 
(18) […]
​
0: Object { idEquipment: "b827eb008bb1", timestamp: 1597948232825, value: 256, … }
​
1: Object { idEquipment: "b827ebb4ceff", timestamp: 1597948294797, value: 0, … }

free 
(17) […]
​
0: Object { idEquipment: "b827eb7945bd", timestamp: 1597948315924, value: 102140, … }
​
1: Object { idEquipment: "b827eb519c39", timestamp: 1597947610314, value: 102396, … }
​
2: Object { idEquipment: "b827eb28ab09", timestamp: 1597947933909, value: 100604, … }
```

And my new array is:

```
new array 
(18) […]
​
0: Object { idEquipment: "b827ebb4ceff", timestamp: 1597948294797, value: 0, … }
​
1: Object { idEquipment: "b827eba1e021", timestamp: 1597948154016, value: 768, … }
​
2: Object { idEquipment: "b827eb15ff2c", timestamp: 1597947773103, value: 1792, … }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newdataList = dataTotalList.map((item,index) => {
    item['value'] -= dataFreeList[index]['value'];
    return item;
})
```

Comment: but 'value' is not defined ?!

Comment: Try now, I made a typo with the keys

Comment: It works but didn't give me what I want because I found out that the values of 1st array are string and values from 2nd array are int, any idea how to convert them to int before processing to subtract ?

Comment: You'll need parseInt

Comment: Even with parsing to Int it still gives me the same values as the totalData array, do you have an idea from where the problem is ?

Comment: Can you post the updated code, including the structure of the original result array?

Comment: Hmm, I tried running it in my console and it worked correctly, the index is undefined error you are getting is because the arrays are not the same length - you'll have to implement some logic there to suit your app's needs

Comment: can't I just make this subtraction in my view (ejs file) ?